# Summernote Not Wroking With Datatables

Tags: javascript, html, datatables, hyperlink, summernote

I am New to Web Programming ....

I have a Problem With including Libraries , I Using Summer note (/*! Summernote v0.7.3 ) For Add Notes And I Using Data Tables And Bootstrap 4.5

```
<script src="template/assets/js/datatables.js"></script>
```

When After Add Above Connection Code

! Summernote Change To Like This

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lq1S.png)

I Changed Up And Down Of Rules and Lines Of Code Libraries Links
But does Not Changes Anything

Like This
**!! up**

```
<script src="template/assets/js/datatables.js"></script>
<script src="template/assets/plugins/summernote/summernote.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**!! Down**

```
<script src="template/assets/plugins/summernote/summernote.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="template/assets/js/datatables.js"></script>
```

> After Removed the Data tables Link Summernote Work Correctly

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHcci.png)

**How I Run this 2 Codes Links Without Crashing Like this**

Comment: Could you please add some code on a platform like JSFiddle, so we can see what you've tried and try to replicate your problem? We'll be able to help easier then. Though, from what you seem to be hinting at, you're trying to edit table content using a rich text plugin?